On Extreme points of unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with respect to the max norm
I was trying to solve the following problem for my non-linear optimization class from the book by Amir Beck.
Let $S=\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \colon \|x\|_{\infty}\leq 1\}$. Show that
$$ext(S)=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \colon x_{i}^2=1, i=1,2, \cdots, n\}$$
First, I am trying to show that any element $x$ from the set on the right-hand side is an extreme point of $S$. Suppose not, i.e., there exists $y$ and $z$ in the right hand set such that
$$x=\lambda y + (1-\lambda)z$$ which implies
$$x_i=\lambda y_i +(1-\lambda) z_i$$ for all $i=1,2,\cdots, n$. Since $x_i$ is either $1$ or $-1$, that implies $1$ and $-1$ can't be an extreme point of $S$, but that is a contradiction. Does that make sense?
How should I prove the other direction?

Take an element that is not in the set on the right, then prove that this point is not an extreme point.

I was trying that. Take an element x not in the set in the right, that means x_j^2 is not equal to 1 for some j. Then how do I show x is not an extreme point? I want to write x as an avg of other two elements in the set, but not sure how to do it

Concerning your forward proof: your logic is: "Assume the corners are not extreme, then they are linear combinations of other points, which contradicts that they are extreme." With that sort of logic, you can prove anything. "Assume Joe Biden isn't Santa Claus. Then he doesn't live at the north pole. But that contradicts him being Santa Claus. QED." (Also, $-1,1$ are not in $S$. $S$ is a subset of $\Bbb R^n$, not $\Bbb R$.)
